# How to insert an interface{} type to mongodb with bulk.Insert()

Tags: mongodb, go

I can't insert a big array into my collection; I have a problem with the `interface{}` type.

Here's the code:

```
collections = getSession().DB("go").C("comments")

func BenchmarkBulkInsert(data interface{}) {
    bulk := collections.Bulk()

    bulk.Insert(data...)
    _, bulkErr := bulk.Run()
    if bulkErr != nil {
        panic(bulkErr)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n - %d comments inserted!", reflect.ValueOf(data).Len())
}
```

I can't build the app.  The error message is this:

> cannot use data (type interface {}) as type []interface {} in argument to bulk.Insert: need type assertion

I'm using the "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" package to connect to the Mongo database, and `data` is an array when I print it to the console.

Comment: You probably want to use `data ...interface{}` instead of `data interface{}`

Comment:  can u explain me ?

Comment: change the function signature `func BenchmarkBulkInsert(data ...interface{})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [variadic func](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions)
So you have to change the input parameter from this :

```
func BenchmarkBulkInsert(data interface{})
```

to this :

```
func BenchmarkBulkInsert(data ...interface{})
```

Comment: hey can u say me if the method that i`m using for insert a array is is written correctly?

Comment: Yeah that's okay.